# Exclude checkout and customer modules/section of magento using varnish-turpentine combination

Tags: magento, caching, plugins, varnish

I am using varnish cache with turpentine plugin on magento 1.8. I don't want varnish to cached my checkout and customer sections/modules

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the caching option in tupertine plugin. You can go to `magento admin->System->Configuration->Tupertine-> Caching Options`.

Now go to URL-based Caching tab and enter `/customer` and `/checkout` or `checkout/onepage/progress` in URL Blacklist box.

Make sure both the entries should be in separate line

Comment: Super helpful details - why don't they put this in their docs or put these in by default!